# Why does this template work in a single file but not across files?

Tags: ats

Consider array.sats:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
fun {a:t@ype} make: (int, a) -> void
```

array.dats:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
staload "./array.sats"

implement {a} make(n: int, x: a) = ()
```

and example.dats:

```
staload Array = "./array.sats"
implement main0() = () where {
        val arr = $Array.make<int>(10, 42)
}
```

These fail to compile with a bunch of template errors:

```
$ make clean all
rm -fv *_[sd]ats.[co] example
removed 'array_dats.c'
removed 'array_dats.o'
removed 'array_sats.c'
removed 'array_sats.o'
removed 'example_dats.c'
patscc -DATS_MEMALLOC_GCBDW -c array.sats
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib/ats2-postiats-0.3.9/ccomp/atslib/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib/ats2-postiats-0.3.9/ccomp/atslib/lib64' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
patscc -DATS_MEMALLOC_GCBDW -c array.dats
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib/ats2-postiats-0.3.9/ccomp/atslib/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib/ats2-postiats-0.3.9/ccomp/atslib/lib64' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
patscc -DATS_MEMALLOC_GCBDW -o example example.dats -lgc
example_dats.c:169:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PMVtmpltcstmat'
ATSINSmove_void(tmp1, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](make<S2Eapp(S2Ecst(g0int_t0ype); S2Eextkind(atstype_int))>)(ATSPMVi0nt(10), ATSPMVi0nt(42))) ;
                      ^
example_dats.c:169:46: warning: implicit declaration of function 'S2Eapp' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ATSINSmove_void(tmp1, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](make<S2Eapp(S2Ecst(g0int_t0ype); S2Eextkind(atstype_int))>)(ATSPMVi0nt(10), ATSPMVi0nt(42))) ;
                                             ^
example_dats.c:169:53: warning: implicit declaration of function 'S2Ecst' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ATSINSmove_void(tmp1, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](make<S2Eapp(S2Ecst(g0int_t0ype); S2Eextkind(atstype_int))>)(ATSPMVi0nt(10), ATSPMVi0nt(42))) ;
                                                    ^
example_dats.c:169:60: error: use of undeclared identifier 'g0int_t0ype'
ATSINSmove_void(tmp1, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](make<S2Eapp(S2Ecst(g0int_t0ype); S2Eextkind(atstype_int))>)(ATSPMVi0nt(10), ATSPMVi0nt(42))) ;
                                                           ^
example_dats.c:169:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'make'
ATSINSmove_void(tmp1, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](make<S2Eapp(S2Ecst(g0int_t0ype); S2Eextkind(atstype_int))>)(ATSPMVi0nt(10), ATSPMVi0nt(42))) ;
                                        ^
example_dats.c:169:99: error: expected expression
ATSINSmove_void(tmp1, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](make<S2Eapp(S2Ecst(g0int_t0ype); S2Eextkind(atstype_int))>)(ATSPMVi0nt(10), ATSPMVi0nt(42))) ;
                                                                                                  ^
2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

Meanwhile the same content in a single file compiles and runs without error:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
extern fun {a:t@ype} make: (int, a) -> void

#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
implement {a} make(n: int, x: a) = ()

implement main0() = () where {
        val arr = make<int>(10, 42)
}
```

What's wrong with the separated code? Very similar code in the `$UNSAFE` files seems to work fine with templates and with a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to staload array.dats:

```
staload Array = "./array.sats"
staload _(*Array*) = "./array.dats"
implement main0() = () where {
        val arr = $Array.make<int>(10, 42)
}
```